# question about pl/sql stored program text

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad, ora-00942

I use TOAD to do my PL/SQL development. In TOAD when i type a procedure name and press f4, I can see this procedure's source code. I think TOAD get the source code from v$sqltext view. To confirm my thought, I wrote a query:

```
select * from v$sqltext
```

but when I execute the upper query, Oracle give me an error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 29 Column: 15

So I think TOAD get the procedure's source from other place instead of v$sqltext view. Anyone can tell me about this? Great thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full query for a stored procedure (not in a package):

```
select text
from   all_source
where  owner = 'MYSCHEMA'
and    type = 'PROCEDURE'
and    name = 'MY_PROCEDURE'
order by line;
```

If you are connected as user MYSCHEMA than you can use USER_SOURCE:

```
select text
from   user_source
where  type = 'PROCEDURE'
and    name = 'MY_PROCEDURE'
order by line;
```

Other values for TYPE are:

- TYPE BODY
- FUNCTION
- TRIGGER
- TYPE
- JAVA SOURCE
- PACKAGE BODY
- PACKAGE

Answer (score 2):

`select * from all_source`

See Database Reference for [ALL_SOURCE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm) and [V$SQLTEXT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2132.htm#i1419389).

Answer (score 1):

If you have select priv on DBA* tables, then do check out `select * from dba_source`. This table will have the entire source code.