# How to search strings inside Oracle Procedures, Functions and Triggers?

Tags: oracle, function, search, stored-procedures, triggers

I need to find strings inside Oracle Procedures, Functions and Triggers.

For SQLServer I use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%m4_plf_par_periodo%'
```

There is something like this for Oracle?

Give me a clue.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754590/question-about-pl-sql-stored-program-text) for the solution using USER_SOURCE.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

you can query [ALL_SOURCE](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http%3a%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fdocs%2Fcd%2FB19306_01%2Fserver.102%2Fb14237%2Fstatviews_2063.htm%23sthref1199) (contains the source to all programs you have access to).

Alternatively, [DBA_SOURCE](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http%3a%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fdocs%2Fcd%2FB19306_01%2Fserver.102%2Fb14237%2Fstatviews_4102.htm%23sthref1841) describes the text source of all stored objects in the database and [USER_SOURCE](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http%3a%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fdocs%2Fcd%2FB19306_01%2Fserver.102%2Fb14237%2Fstatviews_4436.htm%23sthref2338) contains the text source of your stored objects only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Find Database Object" wizard in free Oracle DB tool "SQL Developer".

To be exact, download and install Oracle SQL Developer from Oracle --> Create a new connection to the database, using a power-user --> In the SQL Developer menu choose "View" --> open menu item "Find DB Object" --> *opens a Find Database Object Widget on the left panel* --> Choose the DB connection --> Select specific schemas to search --> Select "All Source Lines" node --> type a string to search --> Click Go.

Expect it to do a non-cases-sensitive wild-card search in all source of Triggers/Procedures/Functions/Packages, owned by the selected schema and display a comprehensive search report of sample lines of code from each object where it was located.